# Independent probability question (Components arriving at a distributor are...)

Tags: probability

Components arriving at a distributor are checked for defects by two different inspectors (each component is checked by both inspectors). The first inspector detects 90% of all defectives that are present, and the second inspector does likewise. At least one inspector does not detect a defect on 20% of all defective components. What is the probability that the following occur?

a. A defective component will be detected only by the first
inspector? By exactly one of the two inspectors?

b. All three defective components in a batch escape detection by both inspectors (assuming inspections of different components are independent of one another)?

*Given solutions are:

a. .10, .20

b. 0*

**My attempt:**

A = defective component will be detected only by the first inspector
B = defective component will be detected by exactly one of the two inspectors
C = all three defective components escape detection by both inspectors

**a.(first part)** There is only one way to achieve event A. That means that first inspector got it right (P=0.9) and at the same time second inspector got it wrong (P=0.1). Since inspectors are independent of each other, solution is:
$$P(A)=0.9*0.1=0.09$$

**a.(second part)** There are two ways of achieving event B. One way is way from the first part and the second one is exactly the same one, just with different roles. Thus,
$$P(B)=(0.9*0.1)+(0.1*0.9)=0.18$$

**b.** If event C occurs, it means that both of inspectors were wrong three times consecutively. Since these "times" are independent of each other, as it is stated in this problem, we use multiplication rule for their occurrence:
$$P(C)=(0.1*0.1)*(0.1*0.1)*(0.1*0.1)=0.000001$$

**My question is related to given solutions. They are not same as my results. Is the reason for that rounding (which means that my results are correct) or I am wrong and my results are not correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct (again).

Here is the solution I found, maybe wrong:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, mistakes like this are really rare in it. That is why I am so confused in such situations. I always blame myself exactly because of the small probability that the book is wrong. :D

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić yes you are right, I just went overboard, sorry, the previous problems' solution was right, i justs vistsed book again, you only saw wrong ques.no.

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić edited